# Should I use typed code contracts for generic interfaces?

Tags: c#, generics, interface, code-contracts

I have a generic interface for a mathematics library, something like this:

```
[ContractClass(typeof(MathsDoubleContracts))]
public interface IMaths<T>
{
    T SomeFunction(T n);
}
```

This enables me to create an `IMaths<double>`, `IMaths<decimal>`, etc. (although at first I only need the `double` version).

I'd like to set up code contracts. At present I've done this:

```
[ContractClassFor(typeof(IMaths<double>))]
public abstract class MathsDoubleContracts : IMaths<double>
{
    public double SomeFunction(double n)
    {
        // Always positive
        Contract.Ensures(0 <= Contract.Result<double>());

        return double.NaN;
    }
}
```

This seems to work, but I'm rather surprised that it does (given that I'm specifying contracts on `IMaths<double>` rather than `IMaths<T>`).

I'm left wondering:

1. Can I specify multiple contract classes on a generic interface, one for each specific type I want to use (e.g. have both `[ContractClass(typeof(MathsDoubleContracts))]` and `[ContractClass(typeof(MathsDecimalContracts))]` attributes on `IMaths<T>`)? Is this a sensible thing to do?
2. Would I be better off *not* using generic interfaces at all (i.e. start with, say, `IMathsDouble` where all the functions are defined in terms of doubles, adding `IMathsDecimal` later)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Q1

Can you bring an example please.

## EDIT

No. It does not allow multiple. Ref [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.contracts.contractclassforattribute.aspx).

```
AttributeUsageAttribute(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
```

Note `AllowMultiple = false`.

## Q2

Yes, although generics might provide some little benefit. Your interface is not really generic. I cannot use `IMaths<File>` for example. I actually answered a different but related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726672/generic-repository-di-aggregation-roots/8726885#8726885).

You may add restrictions such as `where T : ...` but that also will not do since you have to limit to only `int`, `double` while you can only do `where T : struct` which is not the same thing. Here generics is mere a decoration and the abstraction of `IMaths<T>` cannot be used as it is (or can it? can depend on your code) and you need concrete classes or interfaces.

A sub-interface is a safe option here

```
interface IntMaths : IMaths<int>
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have clarified what I meant in Q1.

Answer (score 0):

I'm kind of doing this by applying a contract to a generic interface, the contract type is then inferred at runtime.

My problem however is defining a base abstract interface in a "common code" assembly which applies to an object of type IService then inherit that for type specific implementations that i require.

however I don't have to specify a type specific implementation i could simply (through dependency injection) determine the contract and object type at runtime ...

[Code contract inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9309236/code-contract-inheritance)

I think my issue is making it "portable"